# VRML or X3D to Direct3D object convertor

Tags: direct3d, converters, vrml, x3d

Is there a tool available to convert VRML or X3D file to Direct3D .x object?

Or is there a code snippet for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This one](http://www.micromouse.ca/) is good. Please let me know if anything similar is available.